# Issue with Future in scala 2.12

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, scala-collections

A simple Future implementation is not working in scala 2.12 which run fine in scala 2.11. Run the following code.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.duration._  
import scala.concurrent.Await 

object FuturesExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val f = Future {
        // Doing some job
      }

      val f1 = Future {
        // Doing some job
      }

      f.onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println("Done")
        case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
      }
}
}
```

The above code is throwing exception as follows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$Implicits$.global()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContextExecutor;
```

Any idea, what kind of changes done in scala 2.12 over ExecutionContext API and what would be the work around.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you try to reproduce it with [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7j6HvMANTmKYmxK3c9RYtQ) (you can change Scala version in build settings)? What exact version you're running?

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` is typically a sign that you're mixing stuff from different versions of Scala, for example, you might be compiling with the 2.12 compiler but running with the 2.11 standard library, that kind of thing.